# I do not see camera and light icons in blender

Tags: interface, camera, lighting

I lost my camera and light icons in mode. I have them in scene collection and they are visible. Howerer they are not visible in modes with my object. Light is still being produced and after using CTRL ALT NUMBER PAD 0 I am in camera mode. I just do not have light and camera icons to grab or use "by hand" in blender. They turned invisible. This is what I see in Blender. [image]

Answer (score 6):

Just tap that icon:

[image]

.. to see them again.

The pyramid of the camera (its frustum) is its 'Extras' Viewport overlay. The rectangle is the result of 'Outline Selected'.

Comment: Thank you man. That was it